# Parsimonious way to add north arrow and scale bar to ggmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I am trying to use ggmap to create a map of the protected areas I am working in with a satellite image from google earth underneath.  I can make a very satisfactory image except that it lacks a north arrow and scale bar:

[image]

I'm aware that there are very long winded ways to add these elements (e.g. [here](http://editerna.free.fr/wp/?p=76)) but there must surely be a more parsimonious way to do it!

I've tried using `map.scale` and `north.arrow` but these both give me:

```
Error in polygon(xb + arrow.x * s, yb + arrow.y * s, ...) : 
  plot.new has not been called yet
```

I can get both `map.scale` and `north.arrow` to work in base R using `plot` but then I can't get my satellite image to plot properly.  I can also get what I want using `arrows` and `text` in base R but again these won't work in ggmap.

The code I'm using is below.  You won't have the polygon (so I won't include it in the code) but you'll be able to load the google earth image and replicate the error.

```
library(rgdal)
library(ggmap)
library(GISTools)

# Load satellite picture

map.centre <- c(lon = 35, lat = -2.5)
map <- get_map(location=map.centre, source="google", maptype="satellite", zoom = 8)

# Plot map

ggmap(map, extent= "device")

map.scale(xc= 34, yc= -3, len= 10, units= "Kilometers",
 ndivs= 4, tcol= "black", scol= "black", sfcol="black")

north.arrow(xb= 35.5, yb= -1, len=100, lab="N")
```

From doing a bit of reading it seems like the `map.scale` and `north.arrow` functions aren't recognising the window the `ggmap` function creates as an open graphical window.  I've done some research and tried to fix this but nothing has worked.  Is anyone able to suggest a way to either fix the error I'm receiving or to get a scale bar and north arrow in ggmap without using hundreds of lines of code?

Comment: the `ggsn` package was not working for you? (https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/ggsn/) Also, if you really care about brevity, 'succinct' is 3 fewer characters and $BIGWORD.

Comment: This is the one that works for me: https://github.com/3wen/legendMap I like the look of ggsn, but it's just far too much fiddling to make it work with ggmap, compared to legendMap

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like `map.scale` and `north.arrow` are designed to work with base graphics, but ggplot uses `grid` graphics. I'm not that familiar with graphing spatial data, but as a quick hack for the North arrow, the code below includes two different options:

```
ggmap(map, extent= "device") +
  geom_segment(arrow=arrow(length=unit(3,"mm")), aes(x=33.5,xend=33.5,y=-2.9,yend=-2.6), 
               colour="yellow") +
  annotate(x=33.5, y=-3, label="N", colour="yellow", geom="text", size=4) +
  geom_segment(arrow=arrow(length=unit(4,"mm"), type="closed", angle=40), 
               aes(x=33.7,xend=33.7,y=-2.7,yend=-2.6), colour=hcl(240,50,80)) +
  geom_label(aes(x=33.7, y=-2.75, label="N"),
             size=3, label.padding=unit(1,"mm"), label.r=unit(0.4,"lines"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

I tend to use my own function to draw scalebars on ggmaps. That gives you the fine control to lay it out exactly how you want it. For example,

```
scalebar = function(x,y,w,n,d, units="km"){
  # x,y = lower left coordinate of bar
  # w = width of bar
  # n = number of divisions on bar
  # d = distance along each division

  bar = data.frame( 
    xmin = seq(0.0, n*d, by=d) + x,
    xmax = seq(0.0, n*d, by=d) + x + d,
    ymin = y,
    ymax = y+w,
    z = rep(c(1,0),n)[1:(n+1)],
    fill.col = rep(c("black","white"),n)[1:(n+1)])

  labs = data.frame(
    xlab = c(seq(0.0, (n+1)*d, by=d) + x, x), 
    ylab = c(rep(y-w*1.5, n+2), y-3*w),
    text = c(as.character(seq(0.0, (n+1)*d, by=d)), units)
    )
  list(bar, labs)
}

sb = scalebar(33.5, -3.8, 0.05, 5, 0.3, "degrees" )

# Plot map

ggmap(map, extent= "device") +
  geom_rect(data=sb[[1]], aes(xmin=xmin, xmax=xmax, ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax, fill=z), inherit.aes=F,
            show.legend = F,  color = "black", fill = sb[[1]]$fill.col) +
  geom_text(data=sb[[2]], aes(x=xlab, y=ylab, label=text), inherit.aes=F, show.legend = F)
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. I used it with a meter unit projection. Tweaked the following part `text = c(as.character(seq(0.0, ((n+1)*d)/1000, by=d/1000)), units)` to have km numbers in the scalebar.