# Join two ggmap with R

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I tried to replicate the following image that appeared in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39067838/parsimonious-way-to-add-north-arrow-and-scale-bar-to-ggmap), but I can't merge two maps:

I have use `annotation_custom` but it does not work:

```
library(raster);library(ggmap)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)

g_canarias <- ggplotGrob(
  ggmap( get_map( location = c(lon = mean(c(-18.3, -13.15)),
                           lat = mean(c(27.5, 29.55))),
              zoom = 6,
              maptype = "satellite") ) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-18.3, -13.15), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(27.5, 29.55), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(legend.position = "none",
    plot.background = element_rect(colour = "black"),
    # plot.margin = margin(0, 0, 0, 0),
    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y = element_blank())
)

ggmap( get_map( location = c(lon = mean(c(-9.5, 4.5)),
                         lat = mean(c(35, 44))),
            zoom = 6,
            maptype = "satellite") ) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-9.5, 4.5), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(35, 44), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  xlab("Longitud") + ylab("Latitud") +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Comment: Example google image https://www.google.es/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fi.stack.imgur.com%2FJb21a.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F39067838%2Fparsimonious-way-to-add-north-arrow-and-scale-bar-to-ggmap&docid=Mw8VBMZyDtTvrM&tbnid=MpneWEqjUzX0VM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwj3xebUt-HVAhUKfRoKHbASBc8QMwhiKDEwMQ..i&w=813&h=862&bih=662&biw=1366&q=ADD%20ggmap%20in%20other%20ggmap&ved=0ahUKEwj3xebUt-HVAhUKfRoKHbASBc8QMwhiKDEwMQ&iact=mrc&uact=8

Comment: Can you add a link to what question you are trying to reproduce please. With the addition of `library(ggmap)` the first plot renders, but the second doesnt ; what data is `Spain` - can you add an example?

Comment: You have [link](https://www.google.es/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fi.stack.imgur.com%2FJb21a.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F39067838%2Fparsimonious-way-to-add-north-arrow-and-scale-bar-to-ggmap&docid=Mw8VBMZyDtTvrM&tbnid=MpneWEqjUzX0VM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwj3xebUt-HVAhUKfRoKHbASBc8QMwhiKDEwMQ..i&w=813&h=862&bih=662&biw=1366&q=ADD%20ggmap%20in%20other%20ggmap&ved=0ahUKEwj3xebUt-HVAhUKfRoKHbASBc8QMwhiKDEwMQ&iact=mrc&uact=8) hear

Comment: Edit your question instead of using comments to show your point.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an abstract example (as yours is not reproducible):

```
library(ggmap)
hdf <- get_map("houston, texas")
bb <- unlist(attr(hdf, "bb"))
bb <- c(bb[2], bb[2]+diff(bb[c(2,4)])/3, bb[3]-diff(bb[c(1,3)])/3, bb[3])
ggmap(hdf, extent = "normal") + 
  annotation_raster(hdf, bb[1], bb[2], bb[3], bb[4]) + 
  annotate("rect", xmin=bb[1], xmax=bb[2], ymin=bb[3], ymax=bb[4], fill=NA, color="black", size=1) + 
  coord_quickmap()
```