# How to put North symbol on my ggplot map in R that actually faces north?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a map that I've made using ggplot and I'm trying to add a North symbol to it, so that it faces the correct direction. I've used

```
canada = map_data("worldHires", "Canada")
ggplot(data = canada)
```

to get the map, which I've posted below

[image]

Does anyone know how to add a North Symbol to this map?

Comment: If you don't mind loading another package, there's [ggsn](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggsn/index.html). Otherwise, [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39068041/8877639) a possible solution.

Comment: I can use this solution with ggplot?

Comment: If you're fine with a crude arrow, it should do it. Have a look at the geom_segment [documentation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_segment.html).

Comment: Have a look of my answer in [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/222799/create-an-inset-map-in-r/222812#222812).